# Is testrpc loading my parity ropsten accounts?

Tags: parity, testrpc

I'm not sure I understand how testrpc accounts work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies. I missed the title and voted to close.

**No.**

TestRPC doesn't regard any running blockchain.

You can think of testrpc as a fast RPC interface *emulator* for development purposes. It's an alternative to a node. It isn't a complete implementation and the state isn't persistent between restarts, but it's very convenient for development.

I usually do:

`$ testrpc -u 0 -u 1` to unlock the first two random test accounts (with Ether) that it *conjures up*.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome thanks again Rob, do you know where I can read up on using ether with testrpc?

Comment: TBH I saw the light when another guy showed me.